# HTTP proxy in neo4j

Tags: java, proxy, neo4j, http-proxy

I'm using neo4j community 3.0 on windows. It appears to have trouble making an external request, such as `WITH "http://kimalbrecht.com/ccnr/04-networkuniverse/17-network-interface/data/12-05-15/ccnr-universe-nodes-nn.csv" AS nodes LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM nodes`
The problem is all network traffic is blocked by firewall and allowed only through a proxy. My question is how can I setup  proxy settings for neo4j. I have the environment variable http_proxy setup, but it does not take effect. When I ran `java -jar -Dhttp.proxyHost=<address> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttp.proxyUser=<user> -Dhttp.proxyPassword=<pass> neo4j-desktop-3.0.0.jar` it worked fine.